# How to interpolate 2D spatial data with kriging in Python?

Tags: scikit-learn, kriging, spatial-interpolation, openturns

I have a spatial 2D domain, say [0,1]×[0,1]. In this domain, there are 6 points where some scalar quantity of interest has been observed (e.g., temperature, mechanical stress, fluid density, etc.). How can I predict the quantity of interest at unobserved points? In other words, how may I interpolate spatial data in Python?

For example, consider the following coordinates for points in the 2D domain (inputs) and corresponding observations of the quantity of interest (outputs).

```py
import numpy as np
coordinates = np.array([[0.0,0.0],[0.5,0.0],[1.0,0.0],[0.0,1.0],[0.5,1.],[1.0,1.0]])
observations = np.array([1.0,0.5,0.75,-1.0,0.0,1.0])
```

The X and Y coordinates can be extracted with:

```py
x = coordinates[:,0]
y = coordinates[:,1]
```

The following script creates a scatter plot where yellow (resp. blue) represents high (resp. low) output values.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, c=observations, cmap='viridis')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: Observations at 6 points]

I would like to use Kriging to predict the scalar quantity of interest on a regular grid within the 2D input domain. How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 6):

In [OpenTURNS](http://www.openturns.org/), the [`KrigingAlgorithm`](http://openturns.github.io/openturns/latest/user_manual/response_surface/_generated/openturns.KrigingAlgorithm.html) class can estimate the hyperparameters of a Gaussian process model based on the known output values at specific input points. The `getMetamodel` method of `KrigingAlgorithm`, then, returns a function which interpolates the data.

First, we need to convert the Numpy arrays `coordinates` and `observations` to OpenTURNS `Sample` objects:

```py
import openturns as ot
input_train = ot.Sample(coordinates)
output_train = ot.Sample(observations, 1)
```

The array `coordinates` has shape `(6, 2)`, so it is turned into a `Sample` of size 6 and dimension 2. The array `observations` has shape `(6,)`, which is ambiguous: Is it going to be a `Sample` of size 6 and dimension 1, or a `Sample` of size 1  and dimension 6? To clarify this, we specify the dimension (1) in the call to the `Sample` class constructor.

In the following, we define a Gaussian process model with constant trend function and squared exponential covariance kernel:

```py
inputDimension = 2
basis = ot.ConstantBasisFactory(inputDimension).build()
covariance_kernel = ot.SquaredExponential([1.0]*inputDimension, [1.0])
algo = ot.KrigingAlgorithm(input_train, output_train,
                           covariance_kernel, basis)
```

We then fit the value of the trend and the parameters of the covariance kernel (amplitude parameter and scale parameters) and obtain a metamodel:

```py
# Fit
algo.run()
result = algo.getResult()
krigingMetamodel = result.getMetaModel()
```

The resulting `krigingMetamodel` is a `Function` which takes a 2D `Point` as input and returns a 1D `Point`. It predicts the quantity of interest. To illustrate this, let us build the 2D domain [0,1]×[0,1] and discretize it with a regular grid:

```py
# Create the 2D domain
myInterval = ot.Interval([0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0])
# Define the number of interval in each direction of the box
nx = 20
ny = 10
myIndices = [nx - 1, ny - 1]
myMesher = ot.IntervalMesher(myIndices)
myMeshBox = myMesher.build(myInterval)
```

Using our `krigingMetamodel` to predict the values taken by the quantity of interest on this mesh can be done with the following statements. We first get the `vertices` of the mesh as a `Sample`, and then evaluate the predictions with a single call to the metamodel (there is no need for a `for` loop here):

```py
# Predict
vertices = myMeshBox.getVertices()
predictions = krigingMetamodel(vertices)
```

In order to see the result with Matplotlib, we first have to create the data required by the `pcolor` function:

```py
# Format for plot
X = np.array(vertices[:, 0]).reshape((ny, nx))
Y = np.array(vertices[:, 1]).reshape((ny, nx))
predictions_array = np.array(predictions).reshape((ny,nx))
```

The following script produces the plot:

```py
# Plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
plt.pcolor(X, Y, predictions_array)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: Predictions of the kriging metamodel]

We see that the predictions of the metamodel are equal to the observations at the observed input points.

This metamodel is a smooth function of the coordinates: its smoothness increases with covariance kernel smoothness and squared exponential covariance kernels happen to be smooth.

Comment: Looks like `output_train = ot.Sample(observations,1)` is a syntax error. For me the only solution that worked was making observations a fake 2d array, like so: [[0], [1], [5], [4]]