# Turn a 1D array into a sample by OpenTURNS in Python

Tags: python, kriging, openturns

I'm trying to interpolate responses on a 2D grid by Kriging following this example:
[How to interpolate 2D spatial data with kriging in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330497/how-to-interpolate-2d-spatial-data-with-kriging-in-python/67160095#67160095)

However, when I'm trying to create a sample from 1D array in OpenTURNS,

```
import numpy as np
import openturns as ot
observations = ot.Sample(np.array([1,2,3]))
```

I keep getting this error

```
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Sample'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    OT::Sample::Sample()
    OT::Sample::Sample(OT::UnsignedInteger const,OT::UnsignedInteger const)
    OT::Sample::Sample(OT::UnsignedInteger const,OT::Point const &)
    OT::Sample::Sample(OT::Sample const &,OT::UnsignedInteger const,OT::UnsignedInteger const)
    OT::Sample::Sample(OT::SampleImplementation const &)
    OT::Sample::Sample(OT::Sample const &)
    OT::Sample::Sample(PyObject *)
```

This doesn't do the job either:

```
observations = ot.Sample(np.array([[1],[2],[3]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is because this is an ambiguous situation. The `array` contains 3 values: the `Sample` class does not know if this data corresponds to a sample made of 3 points in dimension 1, or a sample with one point in dimension 3.

The classes which clarify this are:

- the `ot.Point()` class manages a multidimensional real vector - it has a dimension (the number of components),
- the `ot.Sample()` manages collection of points - it has a size (the number of points in the sample) and a dimension (the dimension of each point in the sample).

There are automatic conversions between Python data types and OpenTURNS data types:

- a Python `list` or `tuple` or a 1D numpy `array` is automatically converted to a `ot.Point()`
- a Python `list` of lists or a 2D numpy `array` is automatically converted to a `ot.Sample()`

A common way to create a 1-dimension `Sample` is from a list of floating point numbers.
Please let me illustrate these three constructions.

(Case 1) To create a Point from a 1D array, we just pass it to the `Point` class:

```
import numpy as np
import openturns as ot

array_1D = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
point = ot.Point(array_1D)
print(point)
```

This prints `[1,2,3]`, i.e. a point in dimension 3.

(Case 2) To create a `Sample` from a 2D array, we add the required square brackets.

```
array_2D = np.array([[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]])
sample = ot.Sample(array_2D)
print(sample)
```

This prints:

```
0 : [ 1 ]
1 : [ 2 ]
2 : [ 3 ]
```

This is a sample made of 3 points ; each point has one dimension.

(Case 3) We often have to create a `Sample` from a list of floats. This can be done more easily with a list comprehension.

```
list_of_floats = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
sample = ot.Sample([[v] for v in list_of_floats])
print(sample)
```

This prints the same sample as in the previous example.
The last script:

```
observations = ot.Sample(np.array([[1],[2],[3]]))  
# Oups: should use 1.0 instead of 1
```

works fine on my machine. Please be aware that OpenTURNS only manages points of floating point values, but not of `int` types. This is why I write:

```
observations = ot.Sample(np.array([[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]]))
```

to make this clear enough.
The call to the `array` function is, however, unnecessary. It is simpler to use:

```
observations = ot.Sample([[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]])
```